# Game on empty graph

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Given the empty graph with $n$ vertices. Alice and Bob alternately add one edge to that graph. The person who makes graph connected wins. Who has the winning strategy if Alice moves first.

Comment: What have you tried? What happens for some small values of $n$?

Comment: For $2\leq n\leq 10$, I found with a computer that Alice wins iff $n\in\{2,4,7,8\}$.

Comment: For $2 \le n \le 20$, I found with a computer that Alice wins iff $n \in \{2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16, 19, 20\}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov If you discard $n=2, 3$ this looks like Alice wins if $n$ is congruent to $-1$ or $0$ mod $4$. Maybe one can prove a winning strategy for $n$ based on winning $n-4$.

Comment: @Mike please do not insert Misha's hint into this user's question.  Leave editing to improve, to the OP.

Comment: This game was solved by L. Csirmaz in Connected Graph Game, solution can be found on his webpage https://users.renyi.hu/~csirmaz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will get you started with some observations.

First, every intermediate position is summarized by two parameters:

1. $n_1, \dots, n_k$ with $n_1 + n_2 + \dots + n_k=n$: the number of vertices in each component.
2. $a$: the total number of edges absent from any component.

We don't care which component the absent edges are from: they just tell us how many moves can be made without combining two components.

Second, it's enough to only keep track of whether $a$ is even or odd. That's because, when $a$ is even, even if $a>0$, playing one of the absent edges is never the *only* correct move. If it were, your opponent would respond by playing another absent edge, and $a$ would return to being even and the position would otherwise stay the same. (Formally, we can prove "only the parity of $a$ matters" by induction on the number of edges not yet played.)

Finally, since we only care about the parity of $a$, we also mostly don't care about the sizes of the components. The only thing that matters about them is:

- If we connect two odd components, we get an even component, and the parity of $a$ does not change.
- If we connect two even components, we get an even component back (net loss of one even component), and the parity of $a$ changes.
- If we connect an even and odd component, we get an odd component back (net loss of one even component), and the parity of $a$ changes.

So we can get a much more concise summary of all the *relevant* features of a position:

1. $k_{\text{even}}$: the number of even components.
2. $k_{\text{odd}}$: the number of odd components.
3. $a \bmod 2$: the parity of the number of absent edges.

---

From here, we can continue with an N-position/P-position analysis. A position in the game is an N-position if it's a win for the Next player to move, and a P-position is a win for the Previous player. We can find these recursively, using the rule that:

- If there are only two components left ($k_{\text{even}} + k_{\text{odd}} = 2$), it's an N-position: the next player can join the two components and connect the graph.
- If all moves from the current position lead to N-positions, the current position is a P-position.
- If there is a move from the current position to any P-position, the current position is an N-position.

Use these rules to build a table of N-positions and P-positions; if you are lazy, use a computer. Find a pattern, and prove it by induction. The empty graph has $(k_{\text{even}}=0, k_{\text{odd}} = n, a \bmod 2 = 0)$, so once you know the values of $n$ for which this is an N-position, you know the values of $n$ for which Alice wins.

Comment: So we can conclude that starting position with 2 and 6 vertices are equivalent ? This contradict with you computations...

Comment: @caduk No, because the triples $(0,2,0)$ and $(0,6,0)$ are not equal. Are you by any chance taking the *number of components* modulo $2$? I am only taking the *number of spare edges* modulo $2$.

Comment: ah, yes, my bad...